# Distance from capsule center to point on the surface

Tags: c#, collision-detection, 3d, geometry

this question is engine agnostic, I will use the term "object" to refer to entities in my scene.

The scenario is the following:

- I have 2 entities
- Entity O is a capsule
- Entity C is a point

I want to move B toward A's center but stop on A's surface in the less computationally expansive way I can think about.

I figured I'd work out the distance between the center of the capsule and the point on the surface where I should stop and use it as an offset to my destination point (destinationPoint -= direction * computedDistance), but I don't know how to find that distance.

My question is: can you come up with a better way to achieve my goal and if not can you solve the problem I've stumbled upon in my solution?

This is a representation of the secondary problem. In the figure I know the coordinates of C, O, A, B, and I want to know the length of PO or the coordinates of P.

[image]

Comment: Check for intersection of a line OC with a cylinder expanding capsules' body into infinity. Check if point of intersection P lies within capsules' cylinder body. If not - check for intersection with closest sphere cap of a capsule.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment. Do you think this is something ok to do 100 times every frame?

Comment: why would you want to do that so frequently? Anyway - CPUs crunch through math calculations easily. Don't spend time optimising for bottlenecks that are not there.

Comment: I was thinking about having multiple C entities in my application, ok then I will try your soultion out mate :)

Comment: Sorry to bother you, do you also happen to have some good reference on how to get the intersection point on a cylinder?

Comment: That one is easy - Google for "line cylinder intersection"